# Parsing s-expressions in Go

Tags: go, lisp, interpreter, s-expression

Here's a link to lis.py if you're unfamiliar: http://norvig.com/lispy.html

I'm trying to implement a tiny lisp interpreter in Go. I've been inspired by Peter Norvig's Lis.py lisp implementation in Python.

My problem is I can't think of a single somewhat efficient way to parse the s-expressions. I had thought of a counter that would increment by 1 when it see's a "(" and that would decrement when it sees a ")". This way when the counter is 0 you know you've got a complete expression.

But the problem with that is that it means you have to loop for every single expression which would make the interpreter incredibly slow for any large program.

Any alternative ideas would be great because I can't think of any better way.

Comment: It actually is a parsing problem, not a lisp one. An example of s-expressions could help to answer.

Comment: A counter wouldn't work. Just like with lis.py you need to use stack or recursion to parse code into cons and symbols.

Answer (score 1):

There is an S-expression parser implemented in Go at Rosetta code:

[S-expression parser in Go](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/S-Expressions#Go)

It might give you an idea of how to attack the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You'd probably need to have an interface "Sexpr" and ensure that your symbol and list data structures matches the interface. Then you can use the fact that an S-expression is simply "a single symbol" or "a list of S-expressions".

That is, if the first character is "(", it's not a symbol, but a list, so start accumulating a []Sexpr, reading each contained Sexpr at a time, until you hit a ")" in your input stream. Any contained list will already have had its terminal ")" consumed.

If it's not a "(", you're reading a symbol, so read until you hit a non-symbol-constituent character, unconsume it and return the symbol.

Answer (score 0):

In 2022, you can also test [**eigenhombre/l1**](https://github.com/eigenhombre/l1), a small [Lisp 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Lisp#The_function_namespace) written in Go, by John Jacobsen .

It is presented in "[(Yet Another) Lisp In Go](http://johnj.com/posts/l1/)"

It does include in [commit b3a84e1](https://github.com/eigenhombre/l1/commit/b3a84e158f4a52f618bd7952abf42ca1758dea59) a parsing and tests for S-expressions.

```golang
func TestSexprStrings(T *testing.T) {
    var tests = []struct {
        input sexpr
        want  string
    }{
        {Nil, "()"},
        {Num(1), "1"},
        {Num("2"), "2"},
        {Cons(Num(1), Cons(Num("2"), Nil)), "(1 2)"},
        {Cons(Num(1), Cons(Num("2"), Cons(Num(3), Nil))), "(1 2 3)"},
        {Cons(
            Cons(
                Num(3),
                Cons(
                    Num("1309875618907812098"),
                    Nil)),
            Cons(Num(5), Cons(Num("6"), Nil))), "((3 1309875618907812098) 5 6)"},
    }
```